# Desinstalar MySQL do Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, terminal

Estou tentando desisntalar o MySQL do Ubuntu com o comando

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server --purge
```

Porém toda vez ele me retorna um erro dizendo que o MySQL já está atualizado, eu já tentei usar o `autoremove`, `clean`. Já parei o server mas mesmo assim ele não desinstala, abaixo a resposta ao tentar remover o MySQL

```
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
O pacote 'mysql-server' não está instalado, por isso não será removido
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 11 não atualizados.
1 pacotes não totalmente instalados ou removidos.
Depois desta operação, 0 B adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Configurando mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.25, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Experimente :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar alguma referência sobre os comandos, não acha? Não é muito interessante ele "fazer" e não entender "oque está fazendo"...

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que você não o tem mais instalado:

```
O pacote 'mysql-server' não está instalado, por isso não será removido
```

Você pode seguir os passos contidos nesse tutorial para uma desinstalação completa:
http://tipslegais10.blogspot.com/2013/01/desinstalar-mysql-no-linux-por-completo.html